# How can I find all data properties for a selected HTML option?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, html-select

Is it possible to find all properties like `data-name=""`, `data-client=""` for a selected option in a select element? I want to make an array / object / JSON Object with some information stored in data properties:

```html
<option
    data-category="<?= $product->category; ?>"
    data-color="<?= $product->color; ?>"
    data-price="<?= $product->price; ?>"
    data-priceclient="<?= $product->priceclient; ?>"
    data-um="<?= $product->um; ?>"
    data-x="<?= $product->x; ?>"
    data-y="<?= $product->y; ?>"
    data-z="<?= $product->z; ?>"

    value="<?= $product->id; ?>" <?= $selected; ?> >
        <?= $product->x; ?>x<?= $product->y; ?>x<?= $product->z; ?> cm
</option>
```

I want to make an array like

```js
data['category'] = "<?= $product->category; ?>"
data['color'] = "<?= $product->color; ?>"
```

etc.

Comment: So - you have a (JSON?) array of objects in the page, which you want to select from according to the option that's selected on a drop down?  And from that selection, you want a collection of objects that are comprised of some elements of data on those JSON objects?

Answer (score 2):

You can call .data() for the `option` element so

```
var $selected = $('#myselect option:selected');
var data = $selected.data();
```

Note: If you have used the data api to add any additional data to the element that too will appear

---

Another way using [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

```
var $selected = $('#myselect option:selected');
var data = $selected[0].dataset;// this is a DOMStringMap
var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMStringMap

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/traceline/dnjsy7sj/1/)

For this HTML:

```
<select id="selectCategory">
    <option value="1" data-category="1">Value 1-1</option>
    <option value="2" data-category="1">Value 2-1</option>
    <option value="3" data-category="1">Value 3-1</option>
    <option value="4" data-category="1">Value 4-1</option>
    <option value="5" data-category="1">Value 5-1</option>    
    <option value="10" data-category="2">Value 1-2</option>
    <option value="20" data-category="2">Value 2-2</option>
    <option value="30" data-category="3">Value 3-3</option>
    <option value="40" data-category="3">Value 4-3</option>
    <option value="50" data-category="3">Value 5-3</option>
</select>

<ul id="selectedCategory"></ul>
```

And this code:

```
$(function(){
var selectElement = $("#selectCategory");

var items = [
    {cat:1, col:"red", val:"1 red" },        
    {cat:1, col:"blue", val:"1 blue" },
    
    {cat:2, col:"red", val:"2 red" },
    {cat:2, col:"blue", val:"2 blue" },
    
    {cat:3, col:"red", val:"3 red" },
    {cat:3, col:"blue", val:"3 blue" }
];

// please note: this code id broken out to show you the distinct steps - you can make this much more succinct
function displaySelectedCategory(){
    
    // find the data-category of the selected option
    var selectedCategory = selectElement
                                .find("option:selected")
                                .attr("data-category"); // or data("category")
    
    // filter the items according to the category (this is your array that you want - I think)
    var filtered = $(items).filter(function(index, item){
        // this is the evaluation that filters the list
        return item.cat == selectedCategory;  // || item.name="???"  || item.color="red"
    });
    
    // get a handle on the output destination (emptied)
    var outputElem = $("#selectedCategory").empty();
    
    // traverse the filtered items and append and element, based upon that item, for each
    $(filtered).each(function(index, item){
        var li = $("<li>").text(item.val);
        outputElem.append(li);
    })
}

selectElement.change(displaySelectedCategory);
});
```

It should build a list of "items" based upon what you select in the drop down (and latterly append elements based upon those filtered items so you can see it working)